# Calling Data Factory API within Web Component in ADF

Tags: api, azure, authorization, azure-data-factory

I am in dire need of calling ADF REST API using Web component inside ADF. I've managed to make it work but the problem I have is how to handle authorization of the request? Right now my authorization token is auto generated for me on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linkedservices/createorupdate) but how I can tackle this inside ADF so this will always authorize itself?

With regards,
K